# Fastest way of opening new page

Tags: spring-mvc

What is fastest way in following case(Using spring-webmvc 4.1.2)?

1. There are 3 Controllers and 3 Services.
2. A-Controller call A-Service and show Page-A.
3. B-Controller call B-Service and show Page-B.
4. C-Controller call C-Service and show Page-C.
5. If user click Page-A's submit button, open Page-B.
6. We have to run A-Service before open Page-B.
7. If user click Page-C's submit button, open Page-B.
8. We have to run C-Service before open Page-B.

I don't want to run ServletFilter twice, so I want to avoid forward.
And I don't want to use redirect because of that is too slow.

I have 2 ideas.

1. Call B-Controller and autowire A-Service and C-Service in the B-Service.
   We resolve which service to use according to RequestParameter.
   But I don't know how to autowire in this case.
2. Call B-Controller in the A-Controller.
   But this way is too bad. Because We have to inject component in our own.

Please tell me witch one is good, or Please tell me another best way.

Comment: Exactly. Your second Idea should do the trick. Autowiring your services  are any day better over calling class within a class. Use the autowired object to call that particular class based on the RequestParameter.

Comment: Did you try use interceptors ?

Comment: @hurricane you mean using interceptor instead of using autowire?

Comment: Yes interceptors for this. U can use interceptors with autowired. preHandle is usafull for you.

Comment: @hurricane I got it! Thank you for your information.